# creating linux os for mobile

Tags: linux, mobile-phones

can i use linux os for my mobile.I want to buld a small linux us for my mobile or any other hardware .

Comment: Not to discourage you, but if you mean you want to write this OS yourself, then it's a classic case of "if you need to ask, it's (*way*) over your head".

Answer (score 3):

[Google Android](http://developer.android.com/index.html) is based on Linux (and is OSS)

Answer (score 2):

[Linux From Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/) might be helpful.

Even though it is not talking about building  linux for embedded hardware, it is a good tutorial about how to build a custom linux system from the scratch

Answer (score 2):

Why not use [Maemo](http://maemo.org)?

Answer (score 2):

MeeGo is a gnu/linux based operating system currently in development that specifically targets mobile phones and tablets. It is maintained by The Linux Foundation.

You can download development releases here: http://meego.com/downloads